# how to Shared element transition from a fragment to an activity

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, transition, shared

I have three fragments inside a ViewPager in an activity, I want to achieve shared element transition from one of the fragments to another activity. The transition is from a recycler view which is inside a fragment which is inside a viewpager which is inside an Activity
Activity->ViewPager->Fragment->Recyclerview

I have searched each every places internet but there are info only about shared element transition from one fragment to another and one activity to another.
There is no content about transition from fragment to activity

```
holder.poster.setTransitionName("posterX");
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) con,holder.poster,holder.poster.getTransitionName());
            Log.e("Animation", "Success");
            //startActivity((Activity) con,intent,options.toBundle());
            c.startActivity(intent,options.toBundle());
```

On using the above code the second activity is launched but nothing is visible, For example the second activity contains a FAB which when clicked youtube is launched.
I know where the FAB is so when i click blindly, youtube launched correctly but nothing is visible in second activity

```
D/ViewRootImpl: changeCanvasOpacity: opaque=true
```

Its one of the logcats.
I think this must be the problem!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, I couldn't find anything that helps sorry, but maybe you should reconsider why would you need a Fragment to Activity relation when you could work with a Fragment to Fragment or Activity to Activity relation.

I've solved my problem that way changing my code to a Fragment to Fragment relation and there is plenty documentation and examples about that [Shared Element Transitions](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition)

Comment: so ill try using nested fragments and reply!

Comment: at this moment that's not possible

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the answer, the startActivity calling method is different.
You have to call

```
startActivityFromFragment(fragment, intent, req_code, options.toBundle());
```

from the AppCompactActivity

Comment: I didn't see that method on AppCompatAcitivty. Please edit ur answer

Comment: @LwinMyoAung, I don't know why you can't see this, but this exists in Android Documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity

Comment: you should use `getBaseActivity().startActivityFromFragment..` to access the method

Comment: Looking at the source code for the `Fragment` class, you can see that the `startActivity` method actually "calls" the fragment activity's `startActivity` method (well, not really - it calls `FragmentHostCallback#onStartActivityFromFragment`).

Answer (score 2):

Fragment to Activity is the same as Activity to Activity, Because your Fragment is inside an Activity.

Comment: Theoretically it is correct but practically when you code,you write transition from fragment, because the elements are not in activity its in fragment. So eventually it is fragment to activity.

Comment: @M. Reza Nasirloo could you help me with this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50319202/fragment-to-activity-shared-element-transition-is-not-working

Answer (score 1):

I think using Pairs as below:

```
 Pair[] pairs = new Pair[1];
            pairs[0] = new Pair<View, String>(tvArtifacts, "itemTrans");
            ActivityOptions options = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(getActivity(), pairs);
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ItemDetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("item_name", "item 2");
            if (options != null) {
                startActivity(i, options.toBundle());
            } else {
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

This worked for me!
Thanks..