# How to make shared transition animation from ViewPager to another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, kotlin, android-transitions

I have the next situation. `Activity[FragmentWithPager[PageWithGrid]]` and I want to make trandition animation from `list item` to `DetailFragment` but I don't know wnat I do wrong. I have added the same `transitionName` to views in `list item` and `fragment detail` layouts and try to make transition animatiot with the code below.

```
val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transitionItems.forEach { view ->
    fragmentTransaction.addSharedElement(view, view.transitionName)
}

val fragment = DetailFragment()
val transitionSet = TransitionSet().apply {
     addTransition(ChangeTransform())
     addTransition(ChangeClipBounds())
     addTransition(ChangeBounds())
}
fragment.sharedElementEnterTransition = transitionSet
fragment.sharedElementReturnTransition = transitionSet

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.root, fragment)
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
fragmentTransaction.commit()
```

Comment: Congratulations on getting your transitions to work. Why not create an answer yourself with an explanation what you had to change and select it as the correct answer (before your bounty ends)? I'm sure it will help others in the future too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I did wrong. **Transition name must be unique for each item in list and page if you switch fragment with pager**. Animation began to work when I have added page and list index to each transition name.

[example project](https://github.com/justokay/TransitionAnimationFromViewPager)

Answer (score 3):

Shared Element Transition API is a bit tricky and has some undefined behaviors, Even if you could manage to implement this, The transition wouldn't be smooth, Here's a work around that I've implemented a few month ago:

Instead of directly hosting the `GridFragment` inside the `ViewPagerFragment` add another `Fragment` as a container:

`Activity[ViewPagerFragment[ContainerFragment[GridFragment]]]`

Now you have a simple Fragment to Fragment Transition that works smoothly.

Here is the sample code in [my github repo](https://github.com/MRezaNasirloo/Shared-Element-Fragment-ViewPager)

[Screen Shot](https://streamable.com/1o6eb)

Answer (score 1):

The steps to implement a shared transition is to

- make your transition animation.
- Transition name in your xml view
- Add SharedElement with the fragmentTransition Object along with the target view and the transition that to be performed.

you can have look for reference [1](http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-2/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38593474/how-to-shared-element-transition-from-a-fragment-to-an-activity), [3](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition)

Answer (score 0):

i have found this sample by google it is very helpful and it handles the fragments in a very pretty way 
[google transition sample](https://github.com/google/android-transition-examples/tree/master/GridToPager)

hope it helps u